# HttpURLConnection - Authorization header always is null

Tags: java, spring, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to authenticate to the api here in java spring mvc.

it's just that I'm having problems with my connection, especially when I set setRequestProperty("Authorization", "***");
always returns 401 error
what could i have wrong??

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL("https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"*******************\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\",oauth_timestamp=\"1633463792\",oauth_nonce=\"******\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"**************\"");

            //   conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_consumer_key", "*******************");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_nonce", "********");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_signature", "*******");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA256");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_timestamp", "1633463792");
         //   conn.setRequestProperty("oauth_version", "1.0");


            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            return conn.getRequestMethod() +os + "\n"+responseCode + "\nContent-type:"+ conn.getRequestProperty("Content-Type") + "\nAuthorization: "+ conn.getRequestProperty("Authorization");
          }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

On my return by postman when I call, it appears like this
Why always null?

POSTgrant_type=client_credentials
401
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: null

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say why the authentication with the Here API isn't working, but I can explain why you get `null` for the `Authorization` in your output.

The reason is that the implementation of the `HttpURLConnection` class in the JDK explicitly refuses to return values of security-sensitive headers.

If you take a look at the `getRequestProperty()` method (at the time of writing this is around line 3367 in [sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#L3367)), then you'll see that the method checks whether the header given is one of a number of security-sensitive headers, and if so, returns `null` regardless of whether a value has been set for this header. `Authorization` is indeed one of the headers deemed to be security-sensitive.

If you want to prove that the value of the `Authorization` header has been set, you can try something like the following:

```java
java.lang.reflect.Field requestsField = conn.getClass().getDeclaredField("requests");
requestsField.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println(requestsField.get(conn));
```

For me, this printed something like `sun.net.www.MessageHeader@52a863563 pairs: {Authorization=...}...`, showing that the `Authorization` header had indeed been set.  Note however that this code is nasty reflective hackery, and although it worked for me with JDK 11 I offer no guarantee that it will work with other versions of Java.

In conclusion, I believe you are setting the authorization header.  It's likely you're setting it to an incorrect value, but I'm afraid I can't help you set it to a working value as I have no access to the Here API and have never worked with it myself. I would suggest seeking support from Here.